# how to give condition on displaying value in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Hi i have user model consist of several fields, in that payment_type is one field which return integer value , so based on that value i need to show some string sentence.

class Users(models.Model):
   payment_type=models.IntegerField()

in my admin i need to make condition to display. I am new to django so support

Comment: what do you mean "i need to make condition to display" ? Note that if your question is how to automagically link a label to each  `payment_type` value (assuming a restricted and known set of possible values), then you want to [pass a `choices` argument to your field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) - then you'll have the label for (almost) free.

Answer (score 1):

For choices, you can use [get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) in admin list_display or write your own customized method to get more control of what get displayed in admin panel

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_payment_type_display', )

# or you can write your own method
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_payment_type', ) # method 

    # call get_<field>_display 
    def get_payment_type(self, obj):
        return obj.get_payment_type_display()

    get_payment_type.short_description = 'Payment Type'
```

Comment: IIRC in the case of a field with choices set, Django admin will already automagically use `get_FOO_display` for the list view.

Comment: I added like this in model its fine now class Person(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SHIRT_SIZES).

 thanks.

Comment: This is an awesome solution.